# create a json sing javascript with size parameter

Tags: javascript, json

I'm writing a code that will return result from dynamodb and from this result should be converted to a json, I'm able to do it, but needed a bit more data in it.

Here is my code.

```js
var item = [
{ "max": "0.575", "ingredients": "a" }, 
{ "max": "10.25", "ingredients": "b" }, 
{ "max": "98.5", "ingredients": "c" }
];

var valuesForChart = {
  data: []
};

item.forEach(function(subItem) {
  var names = subItem.ingredients;
  var level = subItem.max;
  valuesForChart.data.push({
[names]: level
  });
});

console.log(valuesForChart);
```

my current output is showing as below.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "a": "0.575"
    },
    {
      "b": "10.25"
    },
    {
      "c": "98.5"
    }
  ]
}
```

but I want it as

```
{
  "data": {
      "a": "0.575",
      "b": "10.25",
      "c": "98.5"
    },
   "max":"98.5"
}
```

Apologies, if the JSON is not in proper format, please let me know how can I do this.

Thanks

Comment: You want `data` to be an object, but you're initializing it as an array : `data: []`. First make it an object : `data: {}` Then add keys/values to it : `data["a"] = "0.575"`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an array `data`since you want a object. Change your `data` declaration and do not use `push`.

Then, calcule your max and put it in `valuesForChart`

```js
var item = [
{ "max": "0.575", "ingredients": "a" }, 
{ "max": "10.25", "ingredients": "b" }, 
{ "max": "98.5", "ingredients": "c" }
];

var valuesForChart = {
  data: {}
};
var max=undefined;
item.forEach(function(subItem) {
  var names = subItem.ingredients;
  var level = subItem.max;
  valuesForChart.data[names] = level
  if(max === undefined || max < level){
     max = level;
 }
});
valuesForChart.max=max;
console.log(valuesForChart);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define object and set property using bracket notation to populate properties

```js
var item = [{
    "max": "0.575",
    "ingredients": "a"
  },
  {
    "max": "10.25",
    "ingredients": "b"
  },
  {
    "max": "98.5",
    "ingredients": "c"
  }
];

var valuesForChart = {
  data: {}, //Define as object
  max: 0
};

item.forEach(function(subItem) {
  var names = subItem.ingredients;
  var level = subItem.max;
  valuesForChart.data[names] = level; //Use Bracket notion to populate

  //Calculate max
  if (valuesForChart.max < parseFloat(level))
    valuesForChart.max = level;

});

console.log(valuesForChart);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `Array.prototype.reduce`.

```js
var item = [{
    "max": "0.575",
    "ingredients": "a"
  },
  {
    "max": "10.25",
    "ingredients": "b"
  },
  {
    "max": "98.5",
    "ingredients": "c"
  }
];
let res = {};
res.data = item.reduce((acc, {
  ingredients,
  max
}) => {
  acc[ingredients] = max;
  return acc;
}, {});
res.max = Math.max(...item.map(({max})=>Number(max)))+"";

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometnihg like this?

```
var item = [
{ "max": "0.575", "ingredients": "a" }, 
{ "max": "10.25", "ingredients": "b" }, 
{ "max": "98.5", "ingredients": "c" }
];

var valuesForChart = {
  "data":{}
};

item.forEach(function(subItem) {  
  valuesForChart.data[subItem.ingredients] = subItem.max;
  var max = valuesForChart.max;
  if(max === undefined || max < subItem.max){
     valuesForChart.max = subItem.max;
 }
});

alert(JSON.stringify(valuesForChart));
```